# How to get Twitter Bootstrap Twipsy to work with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get twitter bootstrap's modal to work with backbone.js.

The backbone view works fine.

```
window.CaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    render: function() {
        var that = this; 
        var tmpl = $("#tmplCase").render(that.model.toJSON());
        $(that.el).html(tmpl);
        return this;
    },
events: {
        "hover #pp-12444"   : "open"
},
open: function() {
        //console.dir(this);
        $('#pp-12444').twipsy('show');
},
    ...
```

The twitter bootstrap js modules have been correctly loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to initialize twipsy first and only then show it:

```
$('#pp-12444').twipsy({'placement': 'above'}).twipsy('show');
```

Comment: thanks, I never initialised it.  I used the following in the end:  `open: function() {
  var that=this;
  var id = '#' + that.el.children[3].children[0].id;
  $(id).twipsy({trigger: "manual",
                              placement: "right",
                              offset: 10,
                              html: true,
                              title: function(){return that.model.get("message");},
                              });
  $(id).twipsy("show"); 
 },`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to include the necessary attributes on your #pp-1244 element? In the twipsy bootstrap demo, the text to display is set in the data-original-title attribute on the element.